# LinkedHashMap assign to new map with different key

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a linkedHashMap with the key being an integer and value an object.
Instead, I need the final hash map to have a string key.
Example:

```
var test:<Int?, User>
If Int==2 then new map should be : "Admin" -> {/..userobject} for that key.
```

I have an enum where every int maps to a certain role. But how do I change the key of the LinkedHashMap to be that string role instead of the integer value of it?
Can I loop through the linkedhashmap to rename the key?

Comment: [`mapKeys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-keys.html) does just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such operation is generally called "mapping" or "transforming" a collection. It applies not only to maps, but to lists and other collections as well.

As you only need to map keys and keep values intact, you can use `mapKeys()` function in Kotlin:

```
val input = mapOf(1 to "foo", 2 to "bar")
val result = input.mapKeys { it.key.toString() }
```

Replace `toString()` with whatever you use to convert int to a string.